# Malfunction with android service launch

Tags: android, android-service

I'm having a problem with my android service which is not starting :  
Here is my code snippet -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

    static String exp_name = "";
    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath") 
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);      
       Log.i("here", "1"); 
    }

    public void onStart(View view) 
    //triggered by start button viz present on R.layout.activity_main
    {
         startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ExperienceLoggerService.class));
         Log.i("here", "2"); 
    }

    ... code....

    //inner class service (needs to be inner class for certain features of my APP)

    public class ExperienceLoggerService extends Service
    {
       @Override
       public void onCreate()
       {
           Log.i("here", "3");
           super.onCreate();
       }

            .....code....
    }

    //back to outer class
    ....other code...... 

}
```

My problem is that my android activity starts normally, 
(i.e.) **"here 1"** gets printed (LogCat) on activity launch, and **"here 2"** get printed when the start button is pressed.
 But the service never starts and neither does **"here 3"** get printed!! I just don't get why?

Here is my android manifest file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nostalgia"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nostalgia.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.nostalgia.StartExperienceActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_start_experience" >
    </activity>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.nostalgia.ExperienceLoggerService"
        android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        android:label="@string/service_name" android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, Inner classes in this case don't work!!
I have to separate them in different class files, and pass resources via Intent. 
(till now i was trying to share resource between the classes by creating inner classes)

Comment: it's because your inner class is not static, and therefore depends on a previously existing instance of MainActivity, which of course android doesn't have when it would try to instanciate the service